# Toyota picnic car

Tags: electrical

My Toyota picnic is giving me problem, when driving on motion the car fired well and after covering some kilometres it started jerking heavily on slow down mode either for pot holes on the road or police check point and moving on speed will not actually show itself but slow down or stop  the engine  will vibrating and eventually stop itself then hard starting will occur at that moment.

After some hours of resting, it will start and run well until it covers some kilometres again before the same problem will reoccur. I have changed plugs, plugs wires, coil, fuel pumps severally, fuel filter, air flow. What do I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Can you read the codes from it? Sounds like a bad sensor if anything that’s making it do that, or perhaps a really bad problem with the head and the valves, but try those codes first, obd2 you can rent a scanner and obd1 you usually jump a pin you can find in your manual and watch a blink of a light to read the codes

Comment: I have also changed one of the firing sensor from the injector mouth, but only left with one the sensor in same injector mouth to be changed

Comment: I have also changed one of the firing sensor from the injector mouth, but only left with one the sensor in same injector mouth to be changed

Comment: Please may i know what you mean by obd2 and obd1

Comment: It’s the cars diagnostic system and it’s way of letting the computer tell you what’s wrong, pull the codes and you pull the general problem

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that could cause an engine to jerk heavily is the intake air flow sensor.

Long time ago, I had a fuel injected 1989 Opel Vectra. It had several issues:

- Occasionally, the check engine light came on. The engine could still run. After checking codes, it showed incorrect voltage from intake air flow sensor.
- In wet weather, acceleration was poor at low RPMs if the engine was cold (but at operating temperature or at high RPMs this wasn't an issue) -- most likely the lambda sensor wasn't at operating temperature yet.
- In very cold weather, the engine sometimes would jerk very violently, so violently I was genuinely worried it could damage something. Most likely, it was so cold the lambda sensor couldn't stay at operating temperature and thus the engine relied solely on the airflow meter.

I suspect all were caused by the same component: intake air flow sensor. This car had a vane-type sensor. It has a vane (against a spring) that is rotated by the airflow into the engine. The vane controls an electrical contact that touches a carbon track. The contact touching the carbon track creates a variable resistor / potentiometer, and the engine measures the value of that resistor to get air flow information.

This type of vane meter that uses a variable resistor suffers from poor contact at the carbon track to electrical contact point. Thus, as they get old, they will have lots of issues.

Modern cars no longer use the vane type meter. They instead have a hot wire meter where a hot wire with temperature-dependent resistance is heated and measured at the same time. It has a control loop where the heating is adjusted to have a constant resistance and thus constant temperature. The heating power needed tells how much air is flowing past the wire.

Most likely, your car doesn't have the same type of meter, but jerking still could be caused by some issue in the intake air flow metering system.